# out of memory exception caused by big array in java

Tags: java, out-of-memory

I'm implenmenting an algorithm which based on probabilistic latent semantic indexing(plsa) and the paper is [here](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/xjwang/acmmm11_plsaannotation.pdf)and it need a four dimension array which named p_z_d_wt_wv, z is topic, d is document, wt is text word, wv is visual word,and the number of each dimension is about 12, 7000,100, 500, and the array is a double array, so it need **32G memory**!! 
I allocate this memory like this way below, and it is just for demonstration as the number of wt and wv in each document is different.

```
p_z_d_wt_wv = new double[12][7000][][]; 
for( int t = 0; t < 12; ++t) 
{ 
    for( int d = 0; d < 7000; ++d ) 
    { 
        p_z_d_wt_wv[t][d] = new double[100][500];
    } 
}
```

when I run the code, it has out of memory problem. 
First, why do my code run out of memory? **Are the memory allocated consecutively if the array are allocated in my way?**  Is it because java have a memory limit for consecutive memory? If so, what's the limit?

Second, what can I do to solve this problem supposed that the memory of the server is big enough.
I know I can change it as a **float** array, but are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 2):

If you actually need all of that memory, well, you need all of that memory.

There are some alternatives:

1. You could look into using memory mapped files.
2. If the array has a lot of zeros in it, you could store it as a sparse matrix representation (don't explicitly store 0s).
3. If you don't need the whole thing in memory at once, you could also store it in some sort of persistent storage (file, database, etc) and only access the parts you need at any given time.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have excluded the 0s in the array,I mean I only store non-zeros. As I will update each element in the array in a loop , so under such condition, could I store it in file or database and how to do it? just another question, why do my code run  out of memory? Is it because java have a memory limit for consecutive array? Thanks

Comment: If you're going remove the zeros, you will need to change how you represent the matrix. You will need to use some maps or other structures designed for this. By default a double array stores 0 for a value, so if you allocate space for it, it will still have a 0 value in. I suggest doing research on sparse matrix representation.

Comment: As for the memory issue, when you start the JVM it has a fixed maximum heap size. You can change this by providing the -Xmx argument. For example, if you give it -Xmx1G the heap will be 1GB. The maximum amount of memory a process can allocate is operating system dependent.

Comment: I would highly recommend usage of `float` here, unless you **absolutely** need the little extra precision.

Answer (score 0):

**Are the memory allocated consecutively if the array are allocated in my way? Is it because java have a memory limit for consecutive memory? If so, what's the limit?**

No, the JVM can not allocate memory for your array.
if you use float for your array, you must set the maximum memory heap space 16GB.
You can use file to store your array.

Comment: store the array in one single file? if so how to read and update the  specific array element and is it slow? thanks for your advice.

Comment: I refer to multiple file. I think it's not slow. You can use RandomAccessFile to update your byte with high performance.