# how to store multi-dimensional array in mongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17583540/out-of-memory-exception-caused-by-big-array-in-java).Simply speaking, my algorithm need a four dimension array. and the size could reach 32G. so I plan to store it in MongoDB. I have implemented it in my way. As I never use MongoDB before, my implementation is too slow, so how should I store this four dimension array in MongoDB?

Some stats:

It would take hours(more than ten I guess,as I didn't wait) to update the whole array as my array size is about 12*7000*100*500, and my server is Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard with 16.0GB ram and cpu is Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU,2.67GHz. My mongoDB version is 2.4.5

Explain my implementation a bit.
**my array has four dimension, name them z, d, wt, wv respectively**.

First,I construct a string for the array element. Take an array element p_z_d_wt_wv[1][2][3][4] for instance, as z is 1, d is 2,wt is 3, wv is 4, I get a string "1_2_3_4", it stand for p_z_d_wt_wv[1][2][3][4].Then I store  the value of p_z_d_wt_wv[1][2][3][4] in the database.
so my data looks like below:

> { "_id" : { "$oid" : "51e0c6f15a66ea5c32a99773"} , "key" : "1_2_3_4" , "value" : 113.1232}
>
> { "_id" : { "$oid" : "51e0c6f15a66ea5c32a99774"} , "key" : "1_2_3_5" , "value" : 11.1243}

Any advice would be appreciated!

Thanks advance!

Below is my code

```
public class MongoTest {

    private Mongo mongo = null;
    private DB mmplsa;
    private DBCollection p_z_d_wt_wv;
    private DBCollection p_z_d_wt_wv_test;
    public void init()
    {
        try{
        mongo = new Mongo();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MongoException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mmplsa = mongo.getDB("mmplsa");
        p_z_d_wt_wv = mmplsa.getCollection("p_z_d_wt_wv");    
    }

    public void createIndex()
    {
        BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("key",1);
            p_z_d_wt_wv.ensureIndex(query,null, true);
    }

    public void add( String key, double value)
    {
        DBObject element = new BasicDBObject();
        element.put("key", key);
            element.put("value", value);
        p_z_d_wt_wv.insert(element);
    }

    public Double query(String key)
    {

        BasicDBObject specific_key = new BasicDBObject("value",1).append("_id", false);
        DBObject obj = p_z_d_wt_wv.findOne(new    BasicDBObject("key",key),specific_key );    
            return (Double)obj.get("value");
    }

    public void update(boolean ifTrainset, String key, double new_value)
    {
        BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject().append("key", key);
        BasicDBObject updated_element = new BasicDBObject();
        updated_element.append("$set", new BasicDBObject().append("value", new_value));
        p_z_d_wt_wv.update(query, updated_element);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also give us some stats on how slow it is ,the machine specifications, mongo version.

Comment: I have add these stats in my posts. Thanks for your remind

Answer (score 0):

Few suggestions

- Since your database size has exceeded(is actually 2X) the size of your RAM. Perhaps you should look at [Sharding](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-clusters/). Mongo works well when you can fit your database size in memory.
- Storing the field **key** as a String not only consumes more memory, string comparisions are slower. We can easily store this field in a `NumberLong`(MongoDB's Long DataType). Since you already know the maximum size of your array is 12*7000*100*500

  I assume the max size of **any** dimension cannot grow over 10,000. And consequently the total number of elements in your collection is less than (10000 ** 4).

  So if you want the element at p_z_d_wt_wv[1](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-clusters/)[2][3][4] 
  You calculate the index as

  (10000 ** 0 * **4**) + (10000 ** 1 * **3**) + (10000 ** 2 * **3**) + (10000 * 3 * **1**)

  You go right to left, increase the power of your base and multiply it with whatever value happens to be in that position and finally take their sum.

  Index this field and we should expect better performance.

Comment: Sharding is intended for preserving high db performance under heavy loads, i.e. to make your system scalable. Very often data size exceeds RAM size (also hundreds times), but sharding is not needed in all these cases. And in some cases sharding might be needed even when data size fits your RAM size. To preserve performance you have to assure just that your _indexes_size_ fits RAM size.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have just a massive array, I suggest you use a memory mapped file.  This will use about 32 GB of disk space and be much more efficient.  Even so, randomly accessing a data set size larger than main memory is always going to be slow unless you have an fast SDD (buying more memory would be cheaper)

I would be very surprised if Mongo DB will perform fast enough for you. If it takes ten hours to update, it is likely to take ten hours to scan once as well.  If you have a SSD, a memory mapped file could take about three minutes.  If the data was all in memory e.g. you had 48 GB (you would need 32+ GB free not total), this would drop to seconds.

You cannot beat the limitations of your hardware. ;)

Comment: Thanks for help. Does memory mapped file in Java have a size limit as the size of the array can reach 32G